# Execute an OpenWhisk Action from within a Python Action on Bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I've written a Python action on Bluemix OpenWhisk, and I need to call another action (actually a binding to a public package) from within this action. A sequence won't do it, because I need to call it a varying number of times with different parameters depending on the input.

[How to invoke openwhisk action within openwhisk platform on bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824336/how-to-invoke-openwhisk-action-within-openwhisk-platform-on-bluemix) mentions how to do it from JavaScript, but the OpenWhisk package doesn't seem to be available for Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions can be invoked using a HTTP request to the [platform API](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/rest_api.md). The Python runtime in OpenWhisk includes the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for making HTTP calls.

Here's an example of an action that calls another (`child`) in the same namespace.

```
import os 
import requests

APIHOST = os.environ.get('__OW_API_HOST')
NAMESPACE = os.environ.get('__OW_NAMESPACE')
USER_PASS = os.environ.get('__OW_API_KEY').split(':')

def main(params):
    action = 'child'
    url = APIHOST + '/api/v1/namespaces/' + NAMESPACE + '/actions/' + action
    response = requests.post(url, data=params, params={'blocking': 'true'}, auth=(USER_PASS[0], USER_PASS[1]))
    print(response.json())

    return {"text": "invoked!"}
```

Swagger documentation for full API is available [here](http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/master/core/controller/src/main/resources/apiv1swagger.json).

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/450) to create a Python client library to make this easier.